# Select2-input breaks after updating html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

Problem description:

I have a form with grouped input/select elements called "Actions". One "Action" has three input elements (2 of them are select2 multi-select elements).
In the form itself I want to be able to have a dynamic amount of "Actions" and therefore I made a template the "Action" and call this template with an ajax request.
The response of this ajax call is the raw html in string format.

graphical representation of what I want to achieve:
[image]

In order to add this html to the parent container of the other "Actions" I use following code:

```
parentContainer.innerHTML += response.response
```

What my current problem is:

After adding the new html content I need to initialize all the select2 items, otherwise they will not be recognized as a select2 item. This all works fine on the first element - but as soon as I add a second "Action" the first "Action" is somehow broken and the select2 items don't work anymore.
I tried to reinitialize those broken select2 items, but that made it even worse and added a second select2 item underneath the first select2 item in the same "Action"

JavaScript for updating select2:

```
$('#Action-'+num).select2();
$('#ActionID-'+num).select2();
$('#ActionParameter-'+num).select2();
```

num represents the id of the new element added.

rendered template structure for one "Action":

```
    <%@page import="xyz.wolfify.moderation.BlacklistActionEnum"%>
    <%
        int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("incrementor"));
    %>
    
    <div id="ActionVisibility-<%=i+1%>" class="action-visibility card border-dark <%if(i<=0){%>mt-5<%}%>">
        <div class="card-header bg-dark">
            <h4 class="m-b-0 text-white action-title">Action <%=i+1%></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -1rem">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Action</label>
                        <select id="Action-<%=i+1%>" class="select2 form-control custom-select action-type" style="width: 100%" onchange="changeAction(this.id)">
                            <% for(BlacklistActionEnum availableType : BlacklistActionEnum.values()) { %>
                            <option value="<%= availableType %>"><%= availableType %></option>
                            <% } %>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ActionIDVisibility-<%=i+1%>" style="display: none" class="col-md-6 action-id-visibility">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Role/Channel ID</label>
                        <select id="ActionID-<%=i+1%>" class="select2 form-control custom-select action-id" style="width: 100%">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ActionParameterVisibility-<%=i+1%>" style="display: none" class="row action-param-visibility">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Parameter</label>
                        <input value="" id="ActionParameter-<%=i+1%>" type="text" class="form-control action-param" style="width: 100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="Remove-<%=i+1%>" type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-outline-danger action-remove" onclick="removeAction(this.id)">Remove this Action</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm thankful for every answer on this problem!

Comment: An example of the rendered HTML structure would be helpful.

Comment: I've edited the initial request and added the html structure :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add the new options by using the append method, and then trigger the change event as described in the documentation

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I'm not searching for a new Option in a select2 itself. It's about adding a whole new select2 item. https://ibb.co/gP1Js0s
The red marked items break after adding a new Action with the "Add Action" button